# Google Analytics not Posting Events for my iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-analytics

I've written an iOS application in Swift, which uses Firebase for it's Database and Authorization. This is just a small portion of my code. I am using a Timer class in a separate file that tracks how much time has been taken. From looking at the logs, the timer class works accurately, and the code inside of the `if let interval = MyTimer.shared.measure(key: "login")` does work, because time is logged to the console.

I am also using Google Analytics to track screens, as well as actions (pressing log-in button, activating after notifications, etc.).

The problem is that I'm just not seeing events in Google Analytic's dashboard. I've waited 2-3 days already, and nothing. I've also been looking at the realtime dashboard. I am seeing that screen tracking is definitely working in real time, it's just events that are not showing up (I am monitoring real time events and events, in general).

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. If someone sees a problem, I definitely appreciate the help.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseAnalytics

class SignInVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var EmailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var PasswordTextField: UITextField!

    public let MAIN_SEGUE = "MainVC"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        MyTimer.shared.start(withKey: "login")

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        guard let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker else { return }
        tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "LogIn Screen")

        guard let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView() else { return }
        tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
    }

    @IBAction func LogIn(_ sender: Any) {

        if (EmailTextField.text != "" && PasswordTextField.text != "") {

        AuthProvider.Instance.login(withEmail: EmailTextField.text!, password: PasswordTextField.text!, loginHandler: { (message) in

            if (message != nil) {
                self.alertUser(title: "Problem with Authentication", message: message!);
            }
            else{

                /// Tracking - Login

                guard let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker else { return }


                if let interval = MyTimer.shared.measure(key: "login") {

                    print("Logging time to login: \(interval)")

                    guard let builder_event = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEvent(withCategory: "Buttons_Events", action: "LogIn", label: "LogIn button pressed", value: interval as NSNumber) else { return}

                    tracker.send(builder_event.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])

                }

                ///

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: self.MAIN_SEGUE, sender: nil)
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            alertUser(title: "Email and Password Required", message: "Please enter a valid email and password");
        }

    }
```

EDIT:

Here is the log for the login. I tried to 'x' out any information that could possibly be personal.

> Logging time to login: 38.25076597929 2017-06-27 17:40:05.256 Example
>   App [xxxxxxxxxxxx] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.17
>   -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:518): Saved   hit: {
>       parameters =     {
>           "&_crc" = 0;
>           "&_s" = 60;
>           "&_u" = ".oyL";
>           "&_v" = "mi3.1.7";
>           "&a" = xxxxxxxxx;
>           "&aid" = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
>           "&an" = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
>           "&av" = "1.0";
>           "&cd" = "LogIn Screen";
>           "&cid" = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
>           "&dm" = "x86_64";
>           "&ds" = app;
>           "&ea" = LogIn;
>           "&ec" = "Buttons_Events";
>           "&el" = "LogIn button pressed";
>           "&ev" = "38.25076597929001";
>           "&sr" = 750x1334;
>           "&t" = event;
>           "&tid" = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
>           "&ul" = en;
>           "&v" = 1;
>           "&z" = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
>           gaiVersion = "3.17";
>       };
>       timestamp = "2017-06-28 00:40:05 +0000"; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been a while since I used GA but from memory I had a similar issue to this in the past. I think the issue was that it only handled integer values for the "value" field of an Event. So your interval being a float is probably the issue. Try explicitly using an Int, you can always just move the decimal point if you need(measure milliseconds).

As a side note, since you already have Firebase in your app. Is there a reason you aren't using Firebase Analytics instead of Google Analytics? In my experience its superior to GA for Mobile Analytics.

Comment: Thank you, man. You might be correct here, as I'm starting to see events in realtime. I ended up just multiplying by 1000, and then taking the floor of that. That gives me a number like 13434.0, which does have one decimal, so I'm wondering if they just want to limit the number of decimals.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. I remember tearing my hair out over a similar issue several years ago it was a bad time haha.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `GAI.sharedInstance().dispatch()` after `tracker.send(builder_event.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])`